# Can my Warlock attack with their familiar and remain invisible?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, familiars, invisibility

I am playing a warlock. I will take the Pact of the Chain option at 3rd level to have the *Find Familiar* spell.

If I cast *invisibility* on myself and then on my turn always take the Attack action to allow my familiar to attack, do I stay invisible?

Answer (score 14):

Strictly speaking, yes.

> The spell ends for a target that attacks or casts a spell.

It doesn't say that it ends for a target that takes the Attack action, so if you take the Attack action and don't attack, then RAW the invisibility stands.

> Additionally, when you take the Attack action, you can
>   forgo one of your own attacks to allow your familiar to
>   make one attack of its own.

Taking the Attack action and then having your familiar do the attack is not you attacking.

You can refer to this post for further clarification on the differences between the Attack action and making an attack: [What does upper-case-A-Attack action vs. lower-case-a-attack mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/what-does-upper-case-a-attack-action-vs-lower-case-a-attack-mean)

Comment: And can I make the familar use the ability help on is turn and attack as reaction in my round?

Comment: @Juilo That would be a different question.

Comment: I know... can i ask it here?

Comment: @Juilo I think the implication is that a new thread is necessary as this is a question that would require its own citations and is a wholly separate question from the original one.

Comment: No worries, I am just new around here and checking how it works. Thanks.